# How can I validate that the feature (user-story) I created meets the requirement of the end user?

Tags: agile, scrum, user-story

How can I validate that the feature (user-story) I created meets the requirement of the end users / stakeholders?

Comment: ask them. if yes then ask them again in a month

Comment: And if after a month they say "no", record what would work better, and create a new user story. Boom. Agile. Sarcasm aside, that really is what agile development is about - quick to market; quick to get feedback; quick to respond. Repeat.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the developer of a system is also the end-user of a system, then the developer cannot perform validation by themselves. Even if the developer is one end-user of the system, the developer can only perform validation for their context and it may be necessary to seek out other stakeholder (customer and user) representatives to validate the system in a broader set of contexts and environments.

Validation, in the software engineering context, is the confirmation "that the requirements for a specific intended use of application have been fulfilled" (ISO/IEC 25000:2014, ISO/IEC/IEEE 15288:2015, ISO/IEC/IEEE 12207:2017) or "the assurance that a product, service, or system meets the needs of the customer and other identified stakeholders" (A Guide to the Project Management Body of Knowledge -- 6th Edition).

Since validation requires an in-depth knowledge of the stakeholders' intended use of the system, someone with that in-depth knowledge needs to perform the validation. If you are building bespoke software for one customer or set of end-users, then it may be possible for the stakeholders to train one or more people from the development organization on the intended use of the software system and have them confirm that the application can fulfill the intended use. However, this approach doesn't scale to software that is produced for multiple groups of stakeholders who may have varying intended uses and contexts for the system.

Development teams should assist in the validation of a system by ensuring that stakeholders have an appropriate place to perform their assessments and by setting up the appropriate events. There's a wide variety of what types of activities would go into validation, depending on what the system is, what the intended use is, and who the stakeholders are.

Answer (score 2):

The user-story is only [a placeholder for a Conversation](https://ronjeffries.com/xprog/articles/expcardconversationconfirmation/). It is part of that conversation to figure out ***with the user*** how to confirm that the feature successfully meets the expectations.

A very effective practice is to explicit the story's [acceptance criteria](https://www.mountaingoatsoftware.com/blog/the-two-ways-to-add-detail-to-user-stories): this allows you to validate that the criteria are met and that the feature should in principle meet expectations. Ultimately, the user would nevertheless need to confirm, because [we value satisfied users more](https://agilemanifesto.org) than just fulfilling agreed criteria, as conversations sometimes miss important details.

Comment: And I very much like the BDD idea of taking notes of that conversation in a manner that is both machine-readable to drive tests, and readable by the subject matter expert/user. Ideally, that would allow the SME to confirm that the example scenarios for the feature are correct. But as Thomas points out, validation is also important and it's not possible to automate the conversation about whether the captured requirements are also the real requirements.

Comment: @amon Thank you for the encouragement.  My initial answer was not incompatible with this view.  I wanted to stress that it's not about contractual negotiation (fulfilling written requirements) but about collaborating with the user (hence the highlighting). I realize that maybe the wording was too ambiguous and edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Not really. That's why we have Agile in the first place.

You can show the user story to the user and ask them whether it matches their requirements. But even if they say "Yes", you still have no idea whether their understanding of the user story matches your understanding, whether their understanding of the requirements matches your understanding, whether the requirements they *want* are actually the requirements they *need*, and whether the requirements they *need* actually make sense.

That's why we deliver a working product at the end of every sprint: the user can *use* the software and *try* whether it does what they need.